# Android app to make encrypted backups of my data to a usb flash drive

Tags: android, backup

I need a Android app to make encrypted backups of my phone data (Images, Documents) to a external usb flash drive.

I tested SanDisk Memory Zone, but it can't encrypt the backups. And I don't like that the backups are not versioned.

I don't want to root my phone for this and I don't need to backup data from inside the app's containers.

Is this possible without using an computer?